# Accessing JADE variable in Underscore template

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, pug, underscore.js-templating

I am passing current user id (userid of logged in user) like

```
app.get('/home', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('home.jade', {
            currentUser : req.user.id 
        });
    });
```

Now this means my home.jade file has access to currentUser variable.

I am able to access this in Jade like

```
p= currentUser
```

But I want to access this variable inside by Underscore template inside

```
script(type='text/template')
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's inline then you should be able to return your variable using `#{}`.

So you'd want

```
script(type='text/template').
    var template = _.template("<b><%- value %></b>");
    template({value: "#{currentuser}"});
```